# Unregister type library on Vista

Tags: com, vb6, idl, typelib

I've made a mistake in IDL file by increasing library version. After that I revert the version. Since the time I can't work with library, because VB6 still write : "There is new version of library *** Do you want to upgrade to version 3.0" ....

in OLE/COM Object viewer I've seen registred some version of my library. Exist some way how to unregister these type library? I try to erase DLL and TLB files from computer, erase all keys from Windows registers ... But "Visual Basic 6" and "OLE/COM Object viewer" still have information about it.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Run `regsvr32 /u Something.DLL` to remove the DLL from the COM registration.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work. Regsvr32 show message box, that unregistred was successful, but "OLE/COM Object viewer" and "VB6" still have informations about library.

Comment: Search the registry for your filename.

Comment: Yep, you'll have to use regedit,search the reg for all mentions of you're dll and remove the applicable keys.

Comment: Another possible technique is to delete the dll and make sure all copies are removed or renamed, then run a regcleaner that can find regentries where the associated file is no longer available, then delete everything that has to do with you're dll. It's a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regsvr32 /u <path to file>` from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work. Regsvr32 show message box, that unregistred was successful, but "OLE/COM Object viewer" and "VB6" still have informations about library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unregister the DLL/TLB that contains the invalid version, otherwise the registry will still contain references to your 'mistake'. If you don't have the file any ore: increase the library version, recompile, and unregister.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (lucky guess)

```
regasm.exe /unregister /tlb my.dll
```